# Compare the efficiency of the data loading methods in deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, numpy-memmap

I need to load a time-series dataset to train a network. The dataset was split into many chunks `train_x_0.npy`, `train_x_1.npy`, ..., `train_x_40.npy` (41 chunks) because of memory issue when I extract these `.npy` files from the raw data. However, their sizes are too large (around 1000 GB) that I couldn't load everything into the RAM. I have been considering two ways to solve this problem.

1. Loading the data chunks using `np.load()` with argument `mmap_mode='r+'`. The memory-mapped chunks are stored in a Python list `self.data`. In the `__getitem__(self, idx)` method of Pytorch `Dataset` class, I convert `idx` to `chunk_idx` and `sample_idx`, then get the sample by `self.data[chunk_idx][sample_idx]`.
2. Extract `.npy` files again from raw data, and save the data sample-by-sample, i.e. one `.npy` file is now one sample, not a data chunk. In the `__getitem__(self, idx)` method, I will get one sample by loading it using `np.load(sample_path)`.

Assuming the Pytorch `DataLoader` will be used to iterate through all samples, then which method will be faster?

If you have another suggestion to extract the raw data or to load the `.npy` files, please share your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both suggested approaches will be limited by your filesystem's IO, since each sample will be loaded from disk on-demand (memory mapping does not speed up the actual loading, once a given patch is requested).

Especially when you are planning to train for many epochs, you can achieve a strong speedup by loading your original chunks `train_x_0.npy`, `train_x_1.npy`, etc. one (or as many as you can hold in RAM) at a time and training multiple epochs on this chunk before switching to the next.

For this, you would need control over the sample indices requested by the `dataloader`. For that you could define a sampler which is passed the sample indices available in the respective cached data chunk. In pseudocode, your training loop could look something like this when caching one chunk at a time:

```
from yourproject import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler

dataset = Dataset(train_data_path, ...)
for chunk_idx in range(num_chunks):
  dataset.cache_chunk(chunk_idx)
  chunk_sample_inds = dataset.get_chunk_sample_inds(chunk_idx)
  chunk_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(chunk_sample_inds)
  chunk_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, sampler=chunk_sampler)
  for chunk_epoch in range(num_chunk_epoch):
    for sample_idx, sample in enumerate(chunk_loader):
       output = model(sample)
```

Hereby, your `Dataset` class needs to take care of

- caching (loading to RAM) a specified chunk, given a chunk idx (indicated by the `cache_chunk` method)
- returning a list of valid sample indices for a given chunk idx (indicated by the `get_chunk_sample_inds` method)

If you use a fast GPU (which is often limited by shuffling data back and forth between RAM and VRAM, even for RAM-cached data), you can expect several orders of magnitude speed up using this approach (as opposed to attempting to fill the VRAM from HDD for each sample).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It seems that your solution trains one chunk in several epochs.
Is it better if we load all the chunks one-by-one in one epoch?
We have to load the chunks multiple times but the model won't be biased to any chunk.

Comment: If you use the samples of a given chunk only once your speedup is basically gone again. You only gain if you load the data once and use it multiple times. Since you say you cannot fit your chunks into ram, I assume each chunk contains a lot of training samples right? Given an appropriate learning rate it is no problem to repeatedly present a subset of training samples before switching to the next (note that the order of the presentation even changes each chunk epoch when using a random sampler). I admit my suggestion is unusual but you will train substantially faster with it, just try it.